# Getting clicked element from ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am populating a dynamic list using javascript. I have a onclick action where I need to get the clicked item from list.
HTML is as:

```
 <div class="cate-map">
    <ul id="option1" onclick="doSelection()">

    </ul>

    </div>
```

I am populating list as:

```
jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            msg = "<li data-input="+data[i]+" class='selected'> <a href=#>"+data[i]+"</a></li>";
            document.querySelector('#option1').innerHTML +=  msg;
        }
    });
```

Onclick Listener is as:

```
function doSelection(){

    var id =$('#option1 li.selected').attr('data-input');
    alert(id);

}
```

Problem is that whenever I click li I am still getting the first element of the list. Not the one I clicked. Please help.

Comment: Learn [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and get rid of ugly inline click handler

Comment: Every `li` you're adding has the "selected" class, so `$('#option1 li.selected')` gets all of them and then `attr` just applies to the first. Look into `jQuery.on` for event listening. `$('#option').on('click','li',function(){});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the selected class is on each element you are appending to the ul. You might want to add the onclick to each list item so you directly have the right context:

```
$('#option1 li').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).data('input'));
});
```

This, of course, needs to be executed after the appending to the DOM has been finished.
Alternatively you can bind the onclick on each element while you are appending:

```
jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
    var $list = $('#option1');

    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var $listItem = $('<li data-input=" + data[i] + " class='selected'> <a href=#>" + data[i] + "</a></li>');

        $listItem.on('click', function(){
            alert($(this).data('input'));
        });

        $list.append($listItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried jquery onclick but was not working for me. I think might be because I am dynamically generating them.

Comment: yes, you have to execute the code above after you appended the list items. Otherwise it will not work. I will extend my answer.

Comment: Hey it worked but still a minor problem. I am getting only single word as aler ie. for 'Movies & Cinema' it gives only Movies. its getting cut wherever space comes.

Comment: Is that something to do with encoding??

Comment: Hey I tried encoding data-value and then decoding before display. And its working. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem. You might want to think of other options to get your data in the onclick handler.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, **we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements** and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

*Example*

```js
$('#option1').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('input');
  alert(id);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [1, 2, 3];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var msg = "<li data-input=" + data[i] + " class='selected'> <a href=#>" + data[i] + "</a></li>";
    $('#option1').append(msg);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cate-map">
  <ul id="option1">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the same but unfortunately the action event itself is not working. Because of this reason I went behind javascript onclick function.